# Slow Connection to Microsoft Dynamics on premises from external network

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

[image]Have Dynamics on premise instance running on local server.
Login going through local AD FS server.

But when trying to connect over internet:

1. AD FS login page loads quick and authenticates quick too
2. But CRM page loads reaally slow (estimate 2-3 min)

How to troubleshoot this proble and understand reason?

Here is a comparison of connection speed to CRM website from local network with and without VPN
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RABU.png)

Comment: Can you bring up the development console in your browser, and have a look at the network tab? I'm inclined to guess that it's *one* resource that's timing out, and the reason for the wait. The network tab will show you a waterfall of the loading.

Comment: There is 3 resources which loads really slow - add screenshot as attachment to question.